# Why does HttpURLConnection not send multiple headers?

Tags: java

I am trying to send multiple headers (accept and auth key) with my request using HttpURLConnection, but only the first gets sent.

```
        URL url = new URL(fileOrUrl);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            for (String h : getHeaders()) {
                String[] keyval = h.split(":");
                if (keyval.length != 2) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
                }
                System.out.println("Setting header " + keyval[0] + ": " + keyval[1]);
                conn.addRequestProperty(keyval[0], keyval[1]);
            }


        System.out.println(conn.getRequestProperties());
        return stream = conn.getInputStream();
```

This results in:

```
Setting header Accept:  application/x-google-protobuf
Setting header Authorization:  apikey
{Accept=[ application/x-google-protobuf]}
```

Why is there only one header being sent?

Comment: I would argue that this is not a duplicate -- someone may not RTFM closely and connect the fact that the authorization header is filtered out from getRequestProperties. It's the same answer, but not necessarily the same question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use wire-shark or similar you should see that both headers are sent.

There is some code in the `HttpURLConnection` implementation class that filters out sensitive headers from the map returned by `getRequestProperties()`.  One of the headers that is filtered out is `"Authorization"`.

The headers that are filtered (in Java 8) are `"Proxy-Authorization"`, `"Authorization"`, `"Cookie"`, and `"Cookie2"`.

Comment: Nice! I was actually testing the code and wondering why is it happening for only the `Authorization` header. Very good answer!

Comment: Makes sense-- I was looking at Java 7 Javadoc!

Comment: The javadocs don't mention this behavior.